# SqlException in the Output but not caught by try-catch

Tags: c#, sql, .net, exception

using `DbContext` I connect to the database and perform simple query:

`var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResultDto>(MyQuery).ToList();`

What's weird to me.. I get all those exceptions after the above line:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
'MatchingService.Server.Host.ConsoleApp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MatchingService.Server.Host.ConsoleApp.exe): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework'. 
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

My question is: Why do I get them in Visual Studio Output window... but I can't catch them in try catch. Here is what I did (with no success):

```
        try
        {
            var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResultDto>(MyQuery).ToList();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

**THE MOST IMPORTANT PART** (I totally forgot)
I receive good data.. This line basically works! But throws exceptions into Output window...

Comment: Make sure that your Visual Studio is configured to break on these exceptions that you are looking at.

Comment: Because they get handled before they ever get to your code, likely by the module that raised them. In VS you can turn on to break when an exception is thrown under DEBUG>EXCEPTIONS for individual exception types. However, unless you have symbols and debug info for the code that is raising the exception you can only look at assembly code. In other words, usually you can ignore those exceptions if they are not bubbled up to your code as they are in internal implementation detail of the library.